# different validations in JPA

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, bean-validation

I am converting a project to JPA2.0 with hibernate implementation and JSF2.0. There is some annotations in the old project like @Length(min = 3) and @NotNull which are imported from org.hibernate.validator.Length; and org.hibernate.validator.NotNull;

In the new project I have two option. First choice,I can still use @Length(min = 3) but with Little bit different import from org.hibernate.validator.constraints.*;(not working with the old import from org.hibernate.validator.Length). second choice, I can convert them to  @Size(min=3) and @NotNull
and use  import javax.validation.constraints.*;

can someone tell me about theses different validations (@Length @Size @NotNUll ) from these imported files
    org.hibernate.validator.*
org.hibernate.validator.constraints.*;
javax.validation.constraints.*;

I am confuse which one is belong to which implementation and version and which one I should go for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of version 4 and later, Hibernate Validator is the reference implementation of the Bean Validation specification (JSR 303/349). The constraints defined in `javax.validation.constraints` (`@Size`, `@NotNull` etc.) are defined by this specification and portable between Bean Validation providers such as Hibernate Validator.

Hibernate Validator 4.x still provides the `@Length` constraint to simplify migration from version 3.x, but if you prefer to solely use the standardized API you should go for `@Size` etc.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, as I understand JPA and beans validation are specifications and Hibernate and Hibernate validation are reference implementation. there is still an unclear part for me , when I am using javax.validation.constraints which reference implementation it means? how about org.hibernate.validator (which reference implementation). if the second one is the refrence implementation of the hibernate what is the first one?

Comment: JPA is a specification in the field of persistence. Hibernate ORM is one implementation of it but not the reference implementation (which is EclipseLink). Bean Validation is a specification in the field of validation, with Hibernate Validator being the reference implementation. The package `javax.validation.constraints` and its types are defined by the Bean Validation specification, while the corresponding constraint validators are provided by an implementation such as Hibernate Validator. Does that answer your question?

Comment: `javax.validation.constraints` reference for Java 7 https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/